# How to handle onChange of Text event in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a ContentView where I have a variable:

```
@State private var textToShow = "Some Text"
```

That I show in:

```
Text(textToShow)
```

I have a button where when I click it, it changes `textToShow` to equal "Changed Text". What is the right way to attach some kind of event that triggers when the Text changes? I am looking for something like a Text(textToShow).onChange(print("Text Changed")).

Note that I do not have any `IBAction` and I am not using any storyboards.

Comment: IMO It doesn't make any sense considering that it is not a TextField therefore you should know when it actually changes.

Comment: So are you saying that in the button action handler where the text changes, I should just fire an event to do whatever I want with the text as opposed to 'watching' for it.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would trigger any side-effects as early as possible. That would be the button-action. If you trigger side-effects from side-effects from side-effects it will become hard to track all changes that may occur when you tap the button. I used to implement such a chain of multiple bindings. It was horrible to maintain.

If you still want to observe the Text-View, then you may just observe the state itself and not the Text-View. Side-effects can be trigged by the View‘s onChange-modifier. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)

```
Text(textToShow)
  .onChange(of: textToShow) { newValue in
    print(...)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also achieve this using an `ObservableObject`.

First, declare a model class that conforms to the `ObservableObject` protocol. This will store the text and apply a didSet property observer.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var textValue: String = "" {
        didSet {
             print("Text changed!")
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it in the relevant view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    // Create observed object
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()

    var body: some View {
        Text($model.textValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this pattern preferred over side-effects? (despite requiring more code?)

Comment: @Rolando I think Nino’s answer is simpler and more elegant for this particular problem. However, the observable object protocol might allow more complex behaviour if needed (multiple properties etc). It is a standard way of tracking the state of a data model in SwiftUI.